# onSend function does not execute it's code when OctoberCMS AJAX calls it

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

i'm trying to execute some code using the October's Data Attribute API for front-end forms. The onSend function executes simple codes like echo 'something', but doesn't more complex code, like trying to use mpdf plugin.
I guess it's related to AJAX reloading the page, but don't know how to solve it.

I tried using data-request from the Data Attribute API, calling the function onSend, but the code on onSend does not execute.

My form header is as follows:

```
<form class="register-form" method="POST" data-request="onSave">
```

and my function onSave:

```
public function onSave(){
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<div style="text-align: center"> Test </div>');
$mpdf->Output();
}
```

Note that both codes are on a component, and the onSave function executes when i try something just like:

```
echo 'Test';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to render / stream a PDF? Have you looked at the network monitor in your browser?

Something I would test is your mpdf code with the `public function onRun()` call. Make sure that works.

Try to update a partial. `data-request-update="'{{__SELF__::partial}}', '#element'"`

Other than that you might need to do a full page redirect. How I stream PDFs is I have a routes.php that takes this `https.domain.com/stream/pdf?id=encryptedsomething`. The route is programmed to look up the specific object in the model after decrypting the `id` and displays the data in a PDF.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. The mpdf library is properly installed, and when i call it on the onRun method it does work. It appears to break only when it's on a method called by the AJAX form submit. My purpose is to generate the pdf file and send it via email, it's a contract filled up with the form data. I've read the docs after the data-request-update attribute, but i don't want to update nothing on the page. Do you think the AJAX call has something to do with the function that is not executing? Btw, the developer console does not show any error. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @GabrielFranco Unfortunately I have not used the mpdf library for a while. I have switched to Renatio's DynamicPDF plugin. I do remember some errors concerning not having `return` in the function. Try adding `return $mpdf->Output();` Other than that you might need to save the data to a model then redirect to a route that then can take that model information and build the PDF that way.

Comment: Alright, i'll try to do it. Ty very much for ur help!

Comment: @GabrielFranco Yes, did that seem to do it for you?

Comment: Hi, your solution was very useful. I did the redirect to a page who renders and sends the pdf. It seems to be a compatibility issue. I was taking a look at Renatio's DynamicPDF, maybe i'll change my way to do it too. Already marked your answer as accepted. Ty again!